# Changing NSCollectionView dragging image while moving mouse around

Tags: macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nscollectionview

I use a NSCollectionView as a toolbox (like in Xcode's Interface Builder). When dragging a tool out of the collection view I would like to change the "dragging image" under the mouse cursor into the real tool image. It should behave similar to Interface Builder when dragging a UI item into the users canvas. Es expected, it should change back to the previous image when I move the mouse back into the collection view.

I tried several delegate methods, but I can't see a way to change the cursor image during mouse movement.

Any suggestions?

Thanks to all! :-)

Regards,

Ulf

Answer (score 0):

1. make a subclass of nscollectionview
2. override

   func beginDraggingSession(with items: [NSDraggingItem], event: NSEvent, source: NSDraggingSource) -> NSDraggingSession
3. use setDraggingFrame(_:contents:)

you can get the mouse point from event.locatoinInWindow (dont forget converting to your collectionview cordinate)